# Oracle SQL - Sum of distinct value belong year, for the first time

Tags: sql, oracle

sorry for the title but is a little difficult to explain the topic in a sigle row..

I have a table like this and i want to know (for each month in the year) the number of employee who have received bonus for the first time.

```
EMPLOYEE_NAME   MONTH   BONUS_RECEIVED
AAA                 1                1
BBB                 1                1

CCC                 2                1
AAA                 2                1
DDD                 2                1

AAA                 3                1
BBB                 3                1
XXX                 3                1
```

So, the result should be

```
MONTH       TOTAL_BONUS
1                     2
2                     2
3                     1
```

- Month 1, employee AAA and BBB receive the bonus (so the result is 2)
- Month 2, employee CCC and DD receive bonus (AAA already received across the year), so the result is 2
- Month 3, only employee XXX has received bonus, because AAA and BBB has already received it across the year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **ROW_NUMBER()** analytic function.

For example,

**Setup**

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (EMPLOYEE_NAME varchar2(3), MONTH number, BONUS_RECEIVED number);

INSERT ALL 
    INTO t (EMPLOYEE_NAME, MONTH, BONUS_RECEIVED)
         VALUES ('AAA', 1, 1)
    INTO t (EMPLOYEE_NAME, MONTH, BONUS_RECEIVED)
         VALUES ('BBB', 1, 1)
    INTO t (EMPLOYEE_NAME, MONTH, BONUS_RECEIVED)
         VALUES ('CCC', 2, 1)
    INTO t (EMPLOYEE_NAME, MONTH, BONUS_RECEIVED)
         VALUES ('AAA', 2, 1)
    INTO t (EMPLOYEE_NAME, MONTH, BONUS_RECEIVED)
         VALUES ('DDD', 2, 1)
    INTO t (EMPLOYEE_NAME, MONTH, BONUS_RECEIVED)
         VALUES ('AAA', 3, 1)
    INTO t (EMPLOYEE_NAME, MONTH, BONUS_RECEIVED)
         VALUES ('BBB', 3, 1)
    INTO t (EMPLOYEE_NAME, MONTH, BONUS_RECEIVED)
         VALUES ('XXX', 3, 1)
SELECT * FROM dual;
```

**Query**

```
SQL> SELECT MONTH,
  2    COUNT(rn) total_bonus
  3  FROM
  4    (SELECT t.*,
  5      row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY employee_name ORDER BY MONTH) rn
  6    FROM t
  7    WHERE BONUS_RECEIVED = 1
  8    )
  9  WHERE rn = 1
 10  GROUP BY MONTH;

     MONTH TOTAL_BONUS
---------- -----------
         1           2
         2           2
         3           1
```

Comment: Many thanks to your reply!!! I've tried to use analytics functions... but sometime are a little difficult to understand..

Comment: @Mistre83 You're welcome! No problem, just practice a few times, you will get used to it :-)

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? I think this perfectly answers OP's question. I would appreciate if a reason is provided for the downvote, so that we could understand the reason.

Comment: Correct. I've marked this as the correct reply and totally reflect my question

Answer (score 2):

A double aggregation solves your problem:

```
select month, count(1) as total_bonus
from (
    select employee_name, min(month) as month
    from table_like_this
    where bonus_received = 1
    group by employee_name
)
group by month;
```

First, for each employee you find the first month he/she received a bonus. Then, you count the number of employees per all "first bonus-received-month found".

Answer (score 1):

U CAN ALSO USE RANK()

```
SELECT MONTH
        ,COUNT(BONUS) AS BONUS
    FROM (
        SELECT EMPLOYEE
            ,MONTH
            ,BONUS
            ,RANK() OVER (
                PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE ORDER BY MONTH
                ) AS RN
        FROM TBTEST
        )
    WHERE RN = 1
    GROUP BY MONTH
```